# How can I break out segments of a 'PHP' file into raw PHP, -and- possible raw HTML -in order-

Tags: php, html, regex, eval, output-buffering

So I've got a concept of how to do this - but actually implementing me is a bit of a stumper for myself; mostly due to my lack of regex experience - but let's get into it.

I'd like to 'parse' through a 'php' file that could contain something like the following:

```
<?php
function Something()
{
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<? Something(); ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
// Some more code or something
?>
```

If interpreted exactly - the above is worthless jibberish - but it is a good example of what I'd like to be able to parse, or interpret...

The idea is that I would read the contents of the above file, and break it out into an ordered array of its respective pieces; while tracking what 'type' each 'segment' is, so that I can either simply echo it, or run an 'eval()' on it.

Effectively, I'd like to end up with an array something like this:

```
$FileSegments = array();

$FileSegments[0]['type'] = "PHP";
$FileSegments[0]['content'] = "
    function Something()
    {
    }";

$FileSegments[1]['type'] = "HTML";
$FileSegments[1]['content'] = "
    <html>
    <body>";

$FileSegments[2]['type'] = "PHP";
$FileSegments[2]['content'] = "Something();"
```

And so on...

The initial idea was to simply 'include()' or 'require()' the file in question, and grab its output from the output buffer - but it dawned on me that I would like to be able to inject some 'top level' variables into each one of these files before evaluating the code. To do this, I would have to 'eval()' my injected code, with the contents of the file after said injection - but in order to do this with the ability to handle raw HTML in the file too, I would have to basically write a temporary clone of the whole file, that just had my injected code written before the actual contents... Cumbersome, and slow.

I hope you're all following here... If not I can clarify...

The only other piece I feel I should note before finalizing this question; is that I would like to retain any variables or symbols in general ( for instance the 'Something() function ) created in segments 0 and 2, for instance, and pass them down to segment '4'... I feel like this might be achievable using the extract method, and then manually writing in those pieces of data before my next segment executes - but again I'm shooting a little in the dark on that.

If anyone has a better approach, or can give me some brief code on just extracting these 'segments' out of a file, I would be ecstatic.

*cheers*

ETA: It dawns on me that I can probably pose this question a little more simply: If there isn't a 'simple' way to do the above, is there a way to handle a String in the *exact* same way that 'require()' and 'include()' handle a File?

Comment: If you have to parse a php file, then don't use regexp but use a PHP [tokeniser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) or [parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) instead

Comment: I don't understand why you need to parse the file to inject variables above the page content.  Just pass everything though your main php file and include the file that was originally intended to be called, this can be done with simple .htaccess rewrite rule.

Comment: Ideally ( up for further evaluation ) I'd like to break all of my '$GLOBALS' variables out into their 'simple' names inside of each file being executed. For instance; rather than having to type out '$GLOBALS['database']' thirty times in a file, I would have the ability to use a '$Database' variable. It may not make a lot of sense to you, and this is only one example; but it's still something I'd like to achieve. If you can't help because you don't see the necessity that's fine, but the question remains.

Comment: The 'why' isn't why I'm here. Not to be cynical or rude; but I'm just looking for the how. All love.

Comment: I might be able to make this question easier too -- Is there a way to 'require' or 'include' a String of text, rather than a file. Or more specifically - evaluate a string of text in the same exact way that the above mentioned functions do to a file.

Comment: _“Cumbersome, and slow”_ – and you think setting up something more complicated on your own will make it less so? Now the question you’ve edited in at the end seems to be your main objective here – so you should probably expand on that (what exactly are you trying to achieve with this). The rest of the original question seems to add a lot of “noise” around what you actually (might) want, and therefor I think it is not very helpful; especially since you might be on the wrong path altogether already. Try and simplify, and focus on the core issue, the task you want solved, not the implementation.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to implement some sort of templating system … now if that’s the case, since you are certainly not the first person attempting that, I’d suggest you look at a couple of existing solutions first. (And keep in mind that PHP _is_ a templating language already – often there is no need to over-complicate by adding another layer on top of that in the first place.)

Comment: The way I see it the intention of the question is clear - the Only question here is what the best way to implement it is. I've mentioned a couple of possible approaches, but I'm not positive which will work, and in the case of the actual question being posed - 'how can I break up X file into X chunks' - I feel that that's entirely answerable...

Comment: This is why I don't like having to resort to asking questions here - more 'why would you do that' answers and comments than 'this is HOW you do that'. Thanks guys. Downvote away - sounds like I'm on my own.

Comment: You say you want to split the php file into $FileSegments, and eval the PHP segments of it. But please consider that your PHP segments are not necessarily complete PHP code you can eval(...). Example: <?php if($condition) {?> <someHtml> <?php } ?>; You won't be able to eval any of both php segments.

Comment: A valid note - and one I do appreciate as I hadn't considered it thoroughly... I suppose I'm after a solution that would encompass this as well. I need to do some reading, but I'm hoping a tokenizer can parse and recognize instances like this. I'm glad someone sees what I'm after lol. Thanks for the feedback; I'll definitely have to keep that in mind as I go through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php    
$str = file_get_contents('filename.php');

    // get values from starting characters
    $php_full = array_filter(explode('<?php', $str));
    $php = array_filter(explode('<?', $str));
    $html = array_filter(explode('?>', $str));


    // remove values after last expected characters
    foreach ($php_full as $key => $value) {
        $php_full_result[] = substr($value, 0, strpos($value, '?>'));
    }

    foreach ($php as $key => $value) {
        if( strpos($value,'php') !== 0 )
        {
            $php_result[] = substr($value, 0, strpos($value, '?>'));
        }
    }

    $html_result[] = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '<?'));

    foreach ($html as $key => $value) {
        $html_result[] = substr($value, 0, strpos($value, '<?'));
    }

    $html_result = array_filter($html_result);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($php_full_result);
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($php_result);
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($html_result);
    echo '</pre>';

?>
```

This will give you 3 arrays of file segments you want, not the exact format you wanted but you can easily modify this arrays to your needs.

For "I'd like to break all of my '$GLOBALS' variables out into their 'simple' names" part you can use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) like

```
extract($GLOBALS);
```